# Marking (multiple) intersection points sinus function and constant function

Tags: pgfplots

The intersection of a sinus and a constant function, has multiple results. So my question is how to mark these points.
My code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} %% om allerhande objecten te gebruiken zoals gradenboog...
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   %at={(0,-12mm)},
    y=10mm,
    width=1*\textwidth,
    axis lines=center,
    xmin=0, xmax=4*pi,
    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
    enlarge y limits,
    enlarge x limits=upper,
    samples=50,
    xtick={0,1.5708,...,22},
    ytick={-2,-1,...,3},
    xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$,$\frac{5\pi}{2}$, $3\pi$, $\frac{7\pi}{2}$, $4\pi$,$\frac{9\pi}{2}$, $5\pi$, $\frac{11\pi}{2}$, $6\pi$,$\frac{13\pi}{2}$, $7\pi$},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    ]
    \addplot[smooth, domain=0:4*pi, very thick, red] {sin(deg(x))};
    \addplot[smooth, domain=0:4*pi] {0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image: sin(x)=0.5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(There may be more elegant ways of doing this.) You can use `name path global` to give a label to each of the plot lines, and `name intersections` (from the `intersections` library) to find the intersections between them. Both of these come from TikZ, so see that manual for more information.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} %% om allerhande objecten te gebruiken zoals gradenboog...
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   %at={(0,-12mm)},
    y=10mm,
    width=1*\textwidth,
    axis lines=center,
    xmin=0, xmax=4*pi,
    ymin=-2, ymax=2,
    enlarge y limits,
    enlarge x limits=upper,
    samples=50,
    xtick={0,1.5708,...,22},
    ytick={-2,-1,...,3},
    xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$,$\frac{5\pi}{2}$, $3\pi$, $\frac{7\pi}{2}$, $4\pi$,$\frac{9\pi}{2}$, $5\pi$, $\frac{11\pi}{2}$, $6\pi$,$\frac{13\pi}{2}$, $7\pi$},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    ]
    \addplot[smooth, domain=0:4*pi, very thick, red,name path global=sine] {sin(deg(x))};
    \addplot[smooth, domain=0:4*pi,name path global=straight] {0.5};

\path [draw,name intersections={of={sine and straight}}]
  (intersection-1) circle[radius=2pt]
  (intersection-2) circle[radius=2pt]
  (intersection-3) circle[radius=2pt]
  (intersection-4) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. Now I've looked in the tikz manual and tkz-euclide manual and tried to name the intersection point with the code (1)     \tkzGetPoint{intersection-1}
  \tkzLabelPoint(intersection-1); But that didn't worked.
(2) \tkzLabelPoint(intersection-2) {(a,b)} gave me a result but isn't automatic.